# Call a function multiple times; how to add the returned value; Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, sum

I am creating a game using Python 3.5 as an exercise.

I have a function that returns a score and I want to sum the score every time the functions is called in order to obtain a final score.

The simplified code is as follows:

```
letter = 'b'

def func(letter):

    score = 0
    word='bye'

    for i in word:
        if letter == i:

            new_word = REMOVE THIS LETTER FROM WORD

            score += 1
            return(new_word, score)
        else:
            return('TRY AGAIN')
```

Now imagine this function is called multiple times in another function, how do I add the scores together to produce a final score?

If my simplified code seems slightly wrong, my main concern is how to sum the numerical return from a function.

Thanks

Comment: Store `score` outside your function

Comment: I have this annoying habit of realising my problem after verbalising it.  I instantly figured out what to do after I clicked send after festering over this problem for a couple hours.

Comment: Returning multiple types, e.g. `tuple(new_word, score)` or `str` makes handling this function very difficult. You may want to reconsider and return a consistent result, e.g. `(old_word, original_score)` for the failure condition. And you are `return`ing in both paths of the condition, so there is no need for a `for` loop, it never gets past `word[0]`

Comment: @ScottLucas No problem! Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new variable `totalScore` that is initialized outside your function, and have it updated each time the function is called.

```
letter = 'b'
totalScore = 0

def func(letter):

    score = 0
    word='bye'

    for i in word:
        if letter == i:

            new_word = REMOVE THIS LETTER FROM WORD

            score += 1
            totalScore += score
            return(new_word, score)
        else:
            return('TRY AGAIN')
```

You can then access `totalScore` whenever it is needed by other functions.